# Issues burning .iso images with 14.r04 Trusty Tahr

Tags: 14.04, iso, dvd, burning, codecs

Hello to the people of Ubuntu Universe! I am having tremendous difficulty burning .iso images on 14.04 Trusty Tahr. I have used Brasero, K3B, and/or XFburn. I have tried just about everything gui possible, as well as command-line (e.g geniso and followed by growisof, even with downloaded and checksum checked .isos).

Each time I've tried with all the Gui burners, they appear to burn even after setting the speed to the lowest possible options. But yet, after the disk ejects, and I put the disk back in, the supposed content isn't there and it appears in the nautilus file browser as Blank Dvd+R.

Same thing occurs with growisof. The list of burn times, speeds and buffer percentages runs all the way to completion in the terminal, but yet the disc is still blank.

I'am wondering if its a codecs issue or a change of codecs that has changed the ability to burn .isos since 12.04 on this machine. But there could be something ridiculously easy that I am not seeing. The permissions of the folder /media/$USER are 0750 (this is the folder in which the device mounts the blank dvd e.g /media/$USER/cdrom0/blankDVD+R). That is also different since 12.04 and previous editions. Formerly the list media mount point of any device (e.g USB or cdrom) was /media/device.

It should be known that the optical drive model is a TSSTcorp DVD+-RW SN-208BB on a Dell Inspiron-3520.

Please I welcome all answers intermediate to advanced!

Jorge Castro do you have any advice? I have read quite few of your post over the past few years about media manipulation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

codecs are not involved with ISO burning. Permissions
would already interfere at the beginning of the burn run.
So it's most probably your drive which fails to burn
the given media in a recognizable way.

You could try a different media type and/or brand
or a different burner drive.

Have a nice day :)

Thomas

Comment: Thomas thank you, that definitely crossed my mind long before posting. I thought against this due to the fact the drive can be used to install software from dvd's that have previously been burned (e.g. reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04 from dvd iso or transferring the Oracle 11g database .zip files from a dvd data disc. Both of which I burned using the same machine and same optical drive.
I found a few articles on the web about driver issues on that particular model of optical drive. It seems windows users have been having the same problem and have to reinstall the driver. But yes you could be right.